# How to map access to entity in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Entity that represents a resource and I save it to the database with hibernate. Now i have users and I want another table that determines whether or not a user has access to the resource. The users are not saved in the database.

In normal SQL i would just have a second table where a line with the resourceid and userid means that the user has access to the resource. But Hibernate seems to make this task really complicated and I cannot figure out what a good way to do this would be.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand ,,The users are not saved in the database."Why? But it is like in SQL

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="UserResource")
public class UserResource {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@ManyToOne
private Resource resource;
@ManyToOne
private User user;
}
```

Comment: I use keycloak for user management so they are only saved by keycloak. I have the id of the user I want to test permissions for. But its no problem i can just save the userid directly instead of a reference to a user, right?
What kind of query would I run to get the Resources a user has the permission to?

Comment: You need to take interface CrudRepository public interface UserToHouseRepository  extends CrudRepository<UserToHouse, Integer> {
    Set<UserToHouse> findAllByHouse(int house);
    UserToHouse findById(int id);
    Set<UserToHouse> findAllByUser(int user);
    UserToHouse findFirstByUserAndHouse(int user,int house);
}